How to override component method from angular storybook
In the component I have a method onExample. I am trying to override the functionality of the onExample method from the storybook. As you can see below, I have tried to add the method as argTypes and inside args. But it does not work. I still get the console output From component. How can I override the method?
In the storybook:
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { applicationConfig, Meta, moduleMetadata, StoryObj } from '@storybook/angular';

const meta: Meta<ExampleComponent> = {
  title: 'Example',
  component: ExampleComponent,
  decorators: [
    applicationConfig({
      providers: [provideAnimations(), importProvidersFrom(ExampleModule)],
    }),
    moduleMetadata({ imports: [ExampleModule] }),
    fullSizeDecorator(),
  ],
    argTypes: {
      onExample: (value: any) => {
        console.log('from story ', value);
      },
  },
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<ExampleComponent>;

export const example: Story = {
  args: {
    onExample: (value: any) => {
        console.log('from story 2', value);
      },
  },
};

In the component example.component.ts
onExample(value): void {
    console.log("From component ", value)
  }


is onExample an input or something like that? If not, i think the only way to do it, is overriding the prototype of ExampleComponent.

@OscarLudick onExample is not an input.
